# How to invoke a function on pressing the "Enter" key

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, event-listener, enter

Here's the JSFiddle link to my app: https://jsfiddle.net/kdowdell24/a9t7b23c/2/

```
document.getElementById("add-button").addEventListener("click", function() {

function createNewItem() {
    //creates div element with a class of "input-item"
    let itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
    itemContainer.classList.add("input-item");

    //creates input element and sets type attribute to "checkbox"
    let checkBoxInput = document.createElement("input");
    checkBoxInput.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkBoxInput.classList.add("check-box");

    //creates input element and sets "type" attribute to "text"
    let textInput = document.createElement("input");
    textInput.setAttribute("type", "text");

    //creates button element and sets "class" to "delete-button" and "type" to "button"
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete-button");
    deleteButton.setAttribute("type", "button");

    //creates Font Awesome "X" icon and adds "fas" and "fa-times" classes
    let xIcon = document.createElement("i");
    xIcon.classList.add("fas");
    xIcon.classList.add("fa-times");

    //adds a div to form
    let formElement = document.getElementById("shopping-list");
    formElement.appendChild(itemContainer);

    //adds checkbox, input, and "delete-button" to div
    itemContainer.appendChild(checkBoxInput);
    itemContainer.appendChild(textInput);
    itemContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);

    //adds "X" icon to button
    deleteButton.appendChild(xIcon);

    //removes checkbox, input and deleteButton from form
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        checkBoxInput.remove();
        textInput.remove();
        deleteButton.remove();
        itemContainer.remove();

    });
};

createNewItem();


//Adds new item after pressing Enter key
let itemList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            createNewItem();
            console.log("New item created!");
        }
    })
}
```

});

```
//Removes all content from list after pressing Clear All button
document.getElementById("clear-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
let listContent = document.querySelectorAll(".input-item");
for (var i = 0; i < listContent.length; i++) {
    listContent[i].remove();
}
```

})

The issue I'm having is with this block of code:

```
//Adds new item after pressing Enter key
let itemList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            createNewItem();
            console.log("New item created!");
        }
    })
}
```

What's happening is that when I press Enter while in the textbox of a list item it adds multiple entries instead of just one. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have only one item entry created below the current one after hitting Enter.

Comment: Your listener is running multiple times because you kept it inside the `for loop`. What excactly do you need to do here? And please post the code of `createNewItem()` in your question too.

Comment: Hey, @KrisD you need to attach the addEventListener to something.  It is just sitting out there.  This is likely causing it to be attached to document or window which means you have many listening on the same node.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have a user create only one additional list item after pressing Enter in the textbox. Right now, it creates several of them at one time after hitting enter.

Comment: That is because of what is known as event bubbling.  Since you are attaching it to the document since you are not clearly stating what the event listener is going to be attached to you have a potential memory leak.  This just means you need to specify what input you are attaching it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a new checkbox when the ENTER key is pressed, just change this:

```
let itemList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            createNewItem();
            console.log("New item created!");
        }
    })
}
```

To this:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter" && (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button')) {
    createNewItem();
    console.log("New item created!");
  }
});
```

I forked your current jsFiddle and used the above code instead here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/3fcgpxrL/30/

Credits to @Moosecouture who mentioned the use of `document.activeElement` to prevent unwanted invokes when an element is in focus during the keypress.

Comment: But do note that the enter key invokes other elements of your page as well. So if you had just clicked the + button and the focus is still on that button, clicking the Enter key would invoke both the + button as well as the function above thus creating two checkboxes at the same time.

Comment: This worked! Although I do see your point about two entries being created when the + is in focus. I'm still learning JavaScript so I'm trying to fine tune my projects as I learn more.

Comment: Glad I could help man. Do mark this as the correct answer if it helped you solve your issue. In the meanwhile, I'll try to fiddle with the above code and see if I can find a workaround for the + focus thing and if I do find something, I'll let you know.

Comment: @KrisD Thanks to Moosecouture's comment, I have edited the code above as well as the jsFiddle to prevent the unwanted invokes when an element is in focus during the keypress.

Comment: @ AndrewL The updated code prevents the unwanted invokes, but it also takes away the Enter functionality for the list items when the textbox input is active.

Comment: Hmmmm.... I think changing the activeElement to only check for focus on the + button should work. Let me check it out.

Comment: @KrisD The updated code above and in the jsFiddle should work fine now.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this just beware Enter on ANY input will trigger a new item so use tab for navigating

```
//Adds new item after pressing Enter key
function keyDownListener (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      createNewItem();
      addListeners()
      console.log("New item created!");
  }
}
function addListeners() {
  let itemList = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
  for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    try {
      itemList[i].removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownListener)
    } catch (error) {

    }
    itemList[i].addEventListener("keydown", keyDownListener)
  }
}
```

Also, People suggest using `.keyCode` which is `13` instead `.key`

Comment: This fixed the issue of multiple entries being added, however the Enter function only appears to work for the first item added and doesn't extend to the newly created ones.

Comment: There it should be fixed now I fully tested it.

Comment: Oh ok... let me try something else.

Comment: So, this update should help.  What you need to do is either identify the new items added or remove the event listeners from the old inputs and then add them again so that everytime you are making sure that every input has the listener on it.

Comment: This should solve and not keep it at the document level as AndrewL is showing.  If you use AndrewL's method I would suggest checking what you are focused on when pressing "Enter".  Using `document.activeElement` this way it won't trigger the issue he has mentioned.

Comment: @Moosecouture Can I add the `activeElement()` approach to my answer. I'll give credits to you for pointing that out.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help on this! Your suggestions have put me on a better track with this project.